# PHP help -- displaying multiple rows

Tags: php

I am fetching some data from a database like this

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 LIKE '%$name%'";
```

And the result of this is many rows, how can i display all the rows using PHP?

If its just for one row i am using this:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 LIKE '%$name%'";       
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$abc_output= "Data Fetched <br />";      
$abc_output .="name: " . $row['name'] . "<br />" ;
$abc_output .="age: " . $row['age'] . "<br />" ; 
$abc_output .="sex: " .  $row['sex'] . "<br />" ; 
$abc_output .='<a href="abc.com"> Back to Main Menu</a>';
 }
echo $abc_output;
```

How can i display for multiple rows?

Comment: You have a concatenation issue.  See your answers.

Comment: why was this down voted??seems nothing wrong in this question..

Comment: @affuzz..:thank you for the suggestion to see answers..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 LIKE '%$name%'";       
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$abc_output= "Data Fetched <br />"; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $abc_output .="name: " . $row['name'] . "<br />" ;
    $abc_output .="age: " . $row['age'] . "<br />" ; 
    $abc_output .="sex: " .  $row['sex'] . "<br />" ; 
    $abc_output .="<hr />";
}

$abc_output .='<a href="abc.com"> Back to Main Menu</a>';
echo $abc_output;
```

Comment: Just to clarify for Ross, you set $abc_output initially outside of the while loop and just appended all of the rows to it.  Otherwise it was overwriting the variable each time.

Answer (score 2):

```
$abc_output= "Data Fetched <br />";
```

This'll reset your string on every row you fetch. You need to concatenate the string everywhere within the loop, or you'll just delete all the previous work:

```
$abc_output .= "Data Fetched <br />";      
            ^--add this.
```